# Does The Binding of Isaac cheat against/for the player?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

When playing *The Binding of Isaac*, I always had the impression that the game, in a way, "cheats" against the player. Often, a run feels like the items you are given (outside of those forced by the player using mechanics like Death Certificate, rerolling, Spindown Dice, etc.) are chosen in a way to actively hinder the player.

Some examples come to mind:

- Items that are mostly avoided (Broken Mirror, Cursed Eye, MissingNo, etc.) tend to spawn on Curse of the Blind floors (so that you recognize them before picking them up).
- Mobs often seem to be chosen as hard counters to the items you were given: Ludovico Technique? Expect spider hell and everything else that moves erratically and very fast. Items that give you creep/floor damage? Everyone flies, including bosses.
- Two-item "you win" combos that include base, no angel/devil items almost never appear (for example, I never managed to get Daddy Long Leg and Gnarled Leaf in the same run outside using Death Certificate).

Obviously, most of the time I just consider these examples as negative reinforcement — just remembering the cursed runs and forgetting the good ones. And since the frequency of cursed runs has been increasing with every DLC (with new, poorly designed mobs added every time), this seems quite reasonable.

That said, considering how imbalanced the game is (see: Unstable Equilibrium on TVTropes), I have started to ask myself if there is anything true in this. Some examples of unfair mechanics include:

- Mobs that can often teleport INSIDE the player with unavoidable damage
- Things like Mom Feet hit you even as you are running around (no delay between the shadow and the stomp).
- Unavoidable damage rooms (either for the current character or for any possible character; see the 4 Cage room spawning on the room door)
- Glitch items (including those from Corrupted Save, MissingNo and the April Fool challenge) can still trigger instant death effects like Plan C and Suicide King. This is taken to the extreme when the effect is not tied to a player command (for example, Suicide King being triggered at the start of a floor). In some cases, a glitch item can even crash the game.
- Mobs that seem to be programmed to seek unavoidable damage situations: for example, The Adversary shoots a homing brimstone laser that is usually countered by standing behind them. Only issue is the fact that they have a weird tendency to get in a corner of the room...
- **Delirium**: This boss is known to constantly use telefrag against the player.
- Multiple bosses and even normal mobs have attacks that simply cannot be avoided if the player has a lower speed stat.

At the same time, some mobs seem to be programmed to avoid unavoidable damage in an attempt to be more fair. Coincidentally, these are mostly the older ones. Again, some examples include:

- Larry Jr. seems to be coded to avoid trapping the player in a non-escape spot and will often turn back at the last second in such cases.
- Despite being based on Bomberman, Wrath seems to have the same logic as Larry, trying to avoid trapping the player between a wall and a bomb.
- Hush homing laser speed apparently is scaled to be relative to the player's speed so that you should always be able to outrun it.

The question is therefore simple: **Does any proof exist that the game contains logic that is actually skewing the gameplay against or for the player?** Sometimes, I could swear that the game is playing some sort of "themed" run on me, with the theme being crafted in a way to be extremely annoying (example: every single "regenerating" mob after giving you Epic Fetus — you will struggle since the bombs are timed and very often won't explode fast enough to stop the mob from regenerating). Or is my mind just playing tricks on me?

Comment: Relevant [meta] post about this question: [Would this question about Binding of Isaac inner working be good for the site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16823/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja simple demonstration that users do not use Meta or that at least guidance given on Meta is not representative of the main site view.

Comment: I agree this is on topic. My close vote was Needs Focus as right now this is at least 3 separate questions.

Comment: I feel you are talking about the 2014 remake, and not the original flash game

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim The main question is "Does The Binding of Isaac cheat against/for the player?" All the other questions are sub-questions that are relevant to answering the main question and are not asking for something completely unrelated.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim there is only one question. **"Does any proof exist that the game contains logic that is actually skewing the gameplay against or for the player?"**. All the rest is just examples of weird behavior in the game that *could* be tied to the game cheating against the player.